# Ef6 dot notation; Join on colums with condition like ,not equals

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to join two tables based on column `ID` on `Table2` to be **like** column `ID` on `Table1`

```
me.dbSet.Join(me.context.Table2, p => p.ID, e => e.ID, 
(p, e) => new { p, e }).Where(z => z.e.ID== uid)
```

the sql output :

```
 SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]  
    FROM  [NG].[T1] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [NG].[T2] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[ID] 
    WHERE [Extent2].[ID] = 'f520f7b3-215d-4dfe-9787-1eb6864fb335'
```

The sql i am trying to write with linq :

```
 SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]  
    FROM  [NG].[T1] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [NG].[T2] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ID] Like [Extent2].[ID] + '%'
    WHERE [Extent2].[ID] = 'f520f7b3-215d-4dfe-9787-1eb6864fb335'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a cross join and `StartsWith` in the `where` clause:

```
var data = from t1 in Table1
           from t2 in Table2
           where t1.Id.StartsWith(t2.Id)
           && t2.Id == uid
           select new { t1, t2 };
```

It won't give the same SQL as you want but the output is the same.

Untested, but using lambda extension methods only, this should work:

```
var data = me.dbSet
    .Join(
        me.context.Table2, 
        p => true, 
        e => true, 
        (p, e) => new { p, e })
    .Where(z => z.e.ID == uid && z.p.Id.StartsWith(z.e.Id));
```

Another potential option if you know that the length of the ID is constant (it looks like a GUID so you can probably rely on it being 36 characters long:

```
var data = me.dbSet
    .Join(
        me.context.Table2, 
        p => p.Id.Substring(0, 36), 
        e => e.Id, 
        (p, e) => new { p, e })
    .Where(z => z.e.ID == uid);
```

Comment: is it posible to write this in dot notation ?

Comment: First of all thaks for your answer. It works but it is very slow when compared with `join on table1.id like table2.id +'%'` becase it joins the tables  `on 1=1 ` and then filters the records. i am testing it with a big dataset which has over  1 million records.

Comment: I thought it might be, though I suspect your original query, while much better, isn't great performance either. If I were you I would see if I could split up the Id in the source so you have two columns, one for the ID and another for the suffix. Then you can add a foreign key for some referential integrity.

Comment: Have added another option that may work for you too. No cross join and no `LIKE` comparison too.

Comment: actually you are right about the database which i am working on it has a bad design.so i am not the guy who created this database.anyway  your query  works great as i expect and exactly with the same performance with query that i am tring to write with linq. i was testing wrong query.